# Somar com valor de um child do firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

**Olá**, Gostaria de **obter o valor** de um **child no firebase**, somar com um número **e atualizar o child** com o resultado da **soma.**

**Código no OnCreate()**

```
uDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Bilhetes").child("total");


    uDataBase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            int total = dataSnapshot.getValue(int.class);

            textoT = total;




        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**Código que publica no banco de dados**

```
result = (textoT + 10);

        uDataBase.setValue(result);
```

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu entendi o que estas querendo fazer, seria apenas ler o child "total", adicionar 10 no valor e gravá-lo novamente no mesmo child, certo ?

Existem algumas formas para se fazer isso, até mesmo formas mais simples, mas se for para apenas um simples incremento no onCreate, sugiro as seguintes alterações :

- Retirar o child("total") do referenciador;
- Substituir addValueEventListener por addListenerForSingleValueEvent (pois vais precisar de apenas um acesso a este child. Caso deixes o addValueEventListener, ele irá ficar monitorando alterações posteriores e consequentemente deixar um observador ativo, ao que me parece pouco interessante neste caso.
- Fazer a leitura do objeto no child("total") e converter para inteiro (tenha certeza que o conteúdo deste campo é um numero inteiro.
- Adicionar 10
- Gravar novamente no mesmo child.

Exemplo prático:

```
uDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Bilhetes");
uDataBase.addListenerForSingleValueEventr(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int total = (int) dataSnapshot.child("total").getValue(); // Carrega o valor do child "total" na variavel inteira total
        total = total + 10;                                       // Incrementa 10 na variavel total (exemplo)
        uDataBase.child("total").setValue(total);                 // Grava a variável total já incremenmtada no child "total"
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Não testei, mas veja ai se funciona.